# how to remove radio selection if query not matched in Access

Tags: ms-access

[image]

[image]

under the Frame "rsa_frame" there is two radio button 1. opt_std 2.opt_elt

my requirement is when i select option 1 it will check the query. if service type combobox value is empty then radio button will lose the focus, if not then proceed further.

```
If IsNull(Me.Service_Type) = True Then
MsgBox "Please fill out #Service Type# "
Else
```

here i get message and till that selection shows none but after the message radio button get selected back. i tried many things but showing error ... request any of you to please help me to solve this

Comment: Even i tried (frame) rsa_frame =" " get remove the focus but even that did not work

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to set focus to combobox when option 1 is selected, consider:

```
Private Sub rsa_frame_AfterUpdate()
If Me.rsa_frame = 1 Then
    If IsNull(Me.Service_Type) Then
        Me.Service_Type.SetFocus
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry i think i was unable to explain what am i looking .. i am trying to explain here again

Comment: Don't edit my answer with more information, edit your question. Or make a comment but editing question with more info about requirement is better.